# Switching Drive on Powershell - Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I've been using Jenkins installation on Windows with a locally created Service Account (Admin) and Jenkins running as a service.
I can access/Switch between D: and C: when I am operating on PowerShell with the same user on the machine.
Unable to do so on Jenkins-powershell. How do I accomplish this?

[image: Jenkins As Service]

[image: Error from Powershell Execution]

[image: Direct PowerShell execution]

[image: Drives on the machine]

Comment: Is drive `D` a network drive? Then you need to [connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-7.2) it for the Jenkins user, as network drives are user-specific.

Comment: It's just the other HDD on the machine however its on AWS. Wondering if that is read as ntwk drive.